How to solve 'cannot install both pin-1-1 and pin-1-1'?
While installing VisPy in a miniconda environment:
> conda install vispy

Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - cannot install both pin-1-1 and pin-1-1

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
└─ pin-1 is installable with the potential options
   ├─ pin-1 1, which can be installed;
   └─ pin-1 1 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')

Doesn't make sense for me, but seems related to Unable to downgrade (python) if (unrelated) packages are pinned and some package needs to be removed

what does that mean?
how to install VisPy safely? (without altering permanently the environment)


The pin-1 1 indicates that you have pinned a package requirement, in this case it looks like it is for python=3.11.*.  Essentially a pin is a requirement that is not allowed to change in your environment.
Pins can come from a number of different sources, but my guess is that you might have a conflict from:

the packages pinned by the file %CONDA_PREFIX%\conda-meta\pinned in your conda environment
OR in the create_default_packages setting in your .condarc file.

How to check the pinned file:
> more %CONDA_PREFIX%\conda-meta\pinned

If this outputs Cannot access file: ...\conda-meta\pinned, then it does not exist and is not the issue.
However, if this contains a pinned python version:
python == 3.11.*

and your current environment is a different python version, this might be causing the conflict.  You can manually edit the file to remove the pin.
How to check your conda config settings:
> conda config --show create_default_packages

If this returns: create_default_packages: [] then no default packages are being added.
However, if this has pinned the python version and it is different than your environment, then it might be causing the pin conflict as well.  This setting can be modified via
conda config --remove create_default_packages <the pin spec>

How to override:
You can also just override the pin by adding the --no-pin flag to the conda command:
conda install vispy --no-pin


Thanks for the detailed answer. I have no pinned file in conda-meta and no default packages. With --no-pin flag I still get the same error.

In case it matters: In .condarc, in addition of the two channels (conda-forge, defaults), I have channel_priority: strict.

If removing that fixes the issue, it is likely a bug in conda.

You can also run the command in verbose mode to get more info: conda install vispy -vvv

Removing channel_priority: strict doesn't change anything, and using the verbose mode doesn't tell me more.

Looks like something is bugged in your environment.  Can you create a new environment and install it?

I did re-create the environment and was able to install vispy. Thanks for the suggestion. I cannot select your answer as it is, but I'll do if you add the possible need to re-create the environment (and perhaps indicate this is possible to extract the # cmd lines from the history file to get the package list to reinstall).
